# MySQL query only returns results if both tables have rows

Tags: mysql, database, multi-table

**Problem:**
In my mysql database, I have two tables **lists** and **shares**. The *lists* table has all of the to do lists that users have created:

[image: 'lists' Table]

The *shares* table stores all lists that have been shared from one user to another:

[image: 'shares' table]

What I want to do is get all lists for a user, both the ones they've created as well as the shared ones they have access to. Currently, I have a select statement that works perfectly when there is an entry in the shares table (doesn't matter if it relates to the specific user I'm retrieving results for).

As soon as I remove the result from the shares table and try to use that same multi-table SELECT statement, I get no results and I can't figure out why.

Here's the SELECT statement that I'm using:

```
SELECT DISTINCT `lists`.* FROM `lists`,`shares` WHERE `lists`.user_id = '$userid' OR (`shares`.sharedwith_id = '$userid' AND `lists`.id = `shares`.list_id) ORDER BY `lists`.datecreated DESC
```

Any help with the query would be awesome. I've looked at JOINs but haven't seen anything that would be more efficient that what I have.

Comment: what about using left join?

Comment: The difference between OUTER JOIN and INNER JOIN visually explained: https://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really should be using `JOIN` instead of `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT DISTINCT `lists`.* 
FROM `lists`
LEFT JOIN `shares`
ON `lists`.`id`=`shares`.list_id AND `lists`.`user_id`=`shares`.`sharedwith_id`
WHERE `lists`.`id` = ?
```

Finally, avoid SQL injection attacks: never embed arguments in your SQL. Pass your arguments as parameters.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try this. Any resources you can point me to about injection that you would recommend? Although, this is coming from a functions file that is not readily available via web (powering an app), I'd like to learn more about the topic!

Comment: Had to modify the query a bit to the below statement but it works! Thanks for the help.